# Is it possible to specify more than one process on a single host node with multiple cores using ABAQUS?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, abaqus

My University has computational nodes with 128 total cores but comprised of two individual AMD processors (i.e., sockets), each with 64 cores. This leads to anomalous simulation runtimes in ABAQUS using crystal plasticity models implemented in a User MATerial Subroutine (UMAT). For instance, if I run a simulation using 1 node and 128 cores, this takes around 14 hours. If I submit the same job to run across two nodes with 128 cores (i.e., using 64 cores/1 processor on two separate nodes), the job finishes in only 9 hours. One would expect the simulation running on a single host node to be faster than on two separate nodes for the same total number of cores, but this is not the case. The problem is that in the latter configuration, each host node contains two processors each with 64 cores and the abaqus_v6.env file therefore contains:

```
mp_host_list=[['node_1', 64],['node_2', 64]]
```

for the 2 node/128 core simulation. The ABAQUS .msg file then accordingly splits the job into two processes each with 64 threads:

```
            PROCESS    1   THREAD     NUMBER OF ELEMENTS
                              1            3840
                              2            3840
                             ...
                             63
                             64            3840
            PROCESS    2   THREAD     NUMBER OF ELEMENTS
                              1            3584
                              2            4096
                             ...
                             63
                             64            3840
```

The problem arises when I specify a single host node with 128 cores because ABAQUS has no way of recognizing that the host node consists of two separate processors. I can modify the abaqus_v6.env file accordingly as:

```
mp_host_list=[['node_1', 64],['node_1', 64]]
```

but ABAQUS just clumps this into one process with 128 threads, and I believe this is why my simulations actually run quicker on two nodes instead of one with the same number of cores, because  ABAQUS does not recognize that it should treat the single node as two processors/processes.

**Is there a way to specify two processes on the same host node in ABAQUS?**

As a note, the amount of memory/RAM reserved per core does not change (~2 GB per core).

**Final update: able to reduce runtimes using multiple nodes**

I found that running these types of simulations across multiple nodes reduces run times. A table of simulation speeds for two models across various numbers of cores, nodes, and cores/processor are listed below.

The smaller model finished in 9.7 hours on two nodes with 64 cores/node = total of 128 cores. The runtime reduced by 25% when simulated over four nodes with 32 cores/node for the same total of 128 cores. Interestingly, the simulation took longer using three nodes with 64 cores/node (total of 192 cores), and there could be many reasons for this.  One surprising result was that the simulation ran quicker using 64 nodes split over two nodes (32 cores/socket) vs. 64 cores on a single socket, which means the extra memory bandwidth of using multiple nodes helps (details of which I do not fully understand).

The larger model finished in ~32.5 hours using 192 cores and there was little between using three (64 cores/processor) or six (32 cores/processor) nodes, which means that at some point, using more nodes does not help. However, this larger model finished in 36.7 hours using 128 cores with 32 cores/processor (four nodes). **Thus, the most efficient use of nodes for both  the larger and smaller model is with 128 CPUs split over four nodes.**

Simulation details for a model with 477,956 tetrahedral elements and 86,153 nodes. Model is cyclically strained to a strain of 1.3% for 10 cycles with a strain ratio R = 0.

| # CPUs | # Nodes | # ABAQUS processes: actual | # ABAQUS processes: ideal | Notes on cores per processor | Wall time (hr) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 32 cores/processor | 13.8 | Using cores on two processors but unable to specify two separate processes |
| 64 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 64 cores/processor | 11.5 | No need to specify two processes |
| 64 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 32 cores/processor | 10.5 | Correctly specifies two processes. **Surprisingly faster than the scenario directly above!** |
| 128 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 64 cores/processor | 14.5 | Unable to specify two separate processes |
| 128 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 64 cores/processor | 8.9 | Correctly specifies two processes |
| 128 | 2 | 2 | 4 | ~32 cores/processor; 4 total processors | 9.9 | Specifies two processes but should be four processes |
| 128 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 64 cores/processor | 9.7 | Specifies two processes over three processors |
| 128 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 32 cores/processor | 7.2 | 32 cores per node. **Most efficient!** |
| 192 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 64 cores/processor | 7.6 | Three nodes with three processors |
| 192 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 64 and 32 cores/processor on both node | 10.5 | Four processors over two nodes |

Simulation details for a model with 4,104,272 tetrahedral elements and 702,859 nodes. The model is strained to 1.3% strain and then back to 0% strain (one cycle).

| # CPUs | # Nodes | # ABAQUS processes: actual | # ABAQUS processes: ideal | Notes on cores per processor | Wall time (hr) | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 64 cores/processor | 53.0 | Using a single processor |
| 128 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 64 cores/processor | 57.3 | Using two processors on one node |
| 128 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 64 cores/processor | 40.9 |  |
| 128 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 32 cores/processor | 36.7 | **Most efficient!** |
| 192 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 64 and 32 cores/processor on both node | 42.7 |  |
| 192 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 64 cores/processor | 32.4 |  |
| 192 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 32 cores/processor | 32.6 |  |

Comment: "One" might need to revisit their expectations. Though you are more likely to have a higher MPI bandwidth and lower MPI latency within the same node, that won't help much if the performance of your application is limited by the memory bandwidth. And in that case, more nodes means more sockets which translates into a higher memory bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for your note! If I can specify the simulation as desired, I will let you know if memory bandwidth was an issue here.

Comment: simply run with 64 core on a single node, and use `taskset`, `numactl` or runtime options to either  pack the cores on a single socket or spread them on two sockets.

Comment: Running on 64 cores is not a problem. Some of my jobs are prohibitively large and 64 cores will not suffice. That is why I want to figure out how to run using 128 cores (or more) in the most efficient manner. These types of crystal plasticity finite element method (CPFEM) simulations often run using many hundreds of cores.

Comment: my point is 64 cores and a single node are enough to figure out whether your app is memory bound or not.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I ran other simulations and concluded that the best use of cores is with 128 cores split over four nodes (using 32 cores/socket). I believe I did determine that the app is memory bound (based on your suggestion)... because the simulation takes 11.5 hours when running on a single 64 core socket on one node, whereas it takes 10.5 hours using 64 cores over two nodes (32 cores/socket). Please let me know if you happen to look over the data in the table I uploaded with any other insight and thanks for your comments!